# TempDB spills when using an UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

TempDB spills when sorting the overall data of two select statements with UNION ALL.

No spills when executing the individual select statements.

Please can you suggest a way of getting rid of tempDB spills.

```
SELECT tbl.protx,tbl.b 
FROM 
(
   SELECT sc.protx,be.b             -- No tempDB spills here
   FROM brandexclude be
   INNER join shipcountries sc ON sc.excluderegion=be.region

   UNION ALL

   SELECT sc.protx,bec.b            -- No tempDB spills here
   FROM brandexcludecountry bec
   INNER JOIN shipcountries sc ON sc.country=bec.country
) tbl  
GROUP BY tbl.protx,tbl.b 
ORDER BY tbl.b,tbl.protx            -- This is causing tempDB spills
```

I have already tried creating indexes and updating statistics, yet no luck!

Link for the actual execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkvAxmqm5

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: I have added the actual execution plan link. Thanks @DanGuzman

Comment: It's not the `UNION ALL` it's the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. Looks like you need better indexes

Comment: What about adding `OPTION (MIN_GRANT_PERCENT = 10)` or some other decent percentage of your server memory, in order to get rid of the spill. Bit of a quick bodge, but I'm thinking indexing this correctly is going to be difficult.

Comment: This is really just a complicated way of writing a `UNION` without `ALL`. It's not any more efficient, as you've discovered. If your base tables are properly indexed and there are very many less rows in the end result than the sources, you can do a `DISTINCT` on each of your base queries and `UNION` those together.